# Can xdotool position the mouse relative to current location?

Tags: command-line, xdotool

Is there any way of choosing not a screen location, but a location relative to where it is?

For example, it could be `xdotool mousemove +5 +0`

Does this exist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll find the answer in the `xdotool` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xdotool.1.html):

> ```
>    mousemove_relative [options] x y
>        Move the mouse x,y pixels relative to the current position of the
>        mouse cursor.
>
>        --polar
>            Use polar coordinates. This makes 'x' an angle (in degrees,
>            0-360, etc) and 'y' the distance.
>
>            Rotation starts at 'up' (0 degrees) and rotates clockwise: 90 =
>            right, 180 = down, 270 = left.
>
>        --sync
>            After sending the mouse move request, wait until the mouse is
>            actually moved. If no movement is necessary, we will not wait.
>            This is useful for scripts that depend on actions being
>            completed before moving on.
>
>            Note that we wait until the mouse moves at all, not necessarily
>            that it actually reaches your intended destination. Some
>            applications lock the mouse cursor to certain regions of the
>            screen, so waiting for any movement is better in the general
>            case than waiting for a specific target.
> ```

In your case it will be:

```
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync 5 0
```

Comment: if you end up here trying to move the mouse relatively and with negative x, y values, you need to `xdotool mousemove_relative -- -5 -10`